# why am I getting duplicate UUID when using api create_uuid?

Tags: php, freeswitch, fusionpbx

I am new at FS and need some help..
I am getting

```
switch_core_session.c:2325 Duplicate UUID!
```

I am using the api create_uuid via ESL. When I check the generated uuid I get a different one every time. I got the error for some time and then it just stopped.

Thank you!!

Comment: Please go read [ask].

Answer (score 0):

Duplicate UUID error will occur if you are creating multiple channels with same UUID. To set custom UUID you need to set `origination_uuid` variable when you want to originate call. If you bridge call like this:

`{origination_uuid=abc}user/1000,user/1001`

uuid `abc` will be set on both channels (1000 and 1001), therefore you will get `Duplicate UUID` error. So if you want to set custom UUID to channel you need to use `[]` brackets instead of `{}` brackets. You can then bridge call like this:

`[origination_uuid=abc]user/100,[origination_uuid=def]user/1001`

`[]` brackets will set channel variables on single channel, and `{}` brackets will set variables on all channels.

You can read more here about channel variables:
https://freeswitch.org/confluence/display/FREESWITCH/Channel+Variables